# Allow user interaction with UIButton during system-provided animation of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

[image]

EDIT: Gif added for clarity

I have a UITableViewCell. The cell contains two sibling elements—a button and a label. When you click the button, new text is loaded into the label.

If the new text is short, and fits on one line (as in the top cell,) all goes well—you can tap that button pretty much as fast as you want.

But if the new text is long, and has to fill two lines or more (as in the bottom cell,) UIKit automatically animates the new text in, sliding it down from the top line. While this automatic animation is happening, UIKit also disables the button so you can't interact with it.

If you try to rapidly click through a few entries in this scenario, it just feels wrong, as the button won't react to every press.

**So my question is:**

Is there any way to enable interaction with the button during this animation? I can turn it off completely using `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)`, but then it doesn't look as nice.

EDIT: Since it was requested, here's the code that updates the label. The text gets updated in didSet whenever the NSManagedObject model changes.

```
extension MasterDataSource {

    private func configure(cell: UITableViewCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? MasterCell else {
            fatalError("Cell Not Returned")
        }
        let category = categories.object(at: indexPath)
        guard let exercises = category.exercises else {
            return
        }
        guard exercises.count > 0  else {
            return
        }
        guard let activeExercise = category.activeExercise else {
            return
        }
        cell.model = MasterCell.Model(with: activeExercise)
    }
}

class MasterCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var exerciseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var nextButton: UIButton!

    struct Model {
        let exercise: Exercise

        init(with exercise: Exercise) {
            self.exercise = exercise
        }
    }

    var model: Model? {
        didSet {
            guard let model = model,
                let exerciseTitle = model.exercise.title else {
                    return
            }
            exerciseLabel.text = exerciseTitle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your relevant code (as text) showing how you update and animate the label.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can do. I didn't post any code because I don't do any animating—as the post states, I'm trying to understand how to modify the ***system-provided*** animation.

Comment: What is the system-provided animation?

Comment: Hi @ElTomato, I just mean the animation that UIKit automatically applies when the text in a label changes from one line to many lines. It doesn't just immediately change the text—the new text actually kind of slides down from the top line. While it's doing that, you can't interact with the button in the cell.

I can turn it off using UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false), but then it doesn't look as nice. I'll see if I can get some gifs of it in my post.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Thanks @ElTomato, I've added a gif and reworded the question for clarity. 

Comment: As far as your question (Is there any way to enable interaction with the button during this animation?) is concerned, nobody can answer it because you don't give a clue as to how you create a table view cell.  Nobody knows how your table view is created by code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add the code back in. The reason I didn't include it is that I thought there was probably just a setting I could enable on the view to allow interaction during UIKit animations.